# Getting a manifest error message when trying to publish a Google Apps Script add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, chrome-web-store

I got my account whitelisted, and now I should be able to publish my add-on.

I went through the this list: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#development_checklist.

But now, when I try to publish it as decribed here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#publish_your_add-on, I get this error message on the developer dashboard:

> Please fix the following errors: The manifest has an invalid install
>   container.

It does not provide much information to me, so i don't know what to do with it.

Can someone tell me how to start?

Comment: I tried to help with a bounty, but seeing that this is a very new field (still in preview, after all), SO might not be the best place to help. You should try, maybe, corresponding Google groups, if any.

Comment: Thank you Xan. I found a google issue with the same problem: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4000 Still not the answer what I want, but it seems, it's a problem on the googles side. Should I close this question?

Comment: Answer your question with the link to that issue (and a bit of explanation) and I'd be happy to award you the bounty.

Comment: Since "it's a known bug" IS an answer for your question, what I propose to do to make an answer out of that. You will be able to close the question by accepting your own answer, and I'll be able to award you well-deserved bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question was published recently on "google-apps-script-issues" bugtracker.

Google aknowledged it as a "whitelist" problem:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4000

The best I can do now is wait.. As suggested on the issue page, if somebody will have the same problem they should star the issue.

Comment: I add the link of the issue. This is the only one with this topic, but it has now 8 watcher, so I think it's a common issue now.

Comment: I've edited the answer a bit. Sorry, I thought at first it was a discussion elsewhere too. Enjoy your [newfound powers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), and use them wisely.